# Elastic search cluster is shown as red. How to recover?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a ES cluster showing the status as red.

{
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
    "status": "red",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 10,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 7,
    "active_primary_shards": 4431,
    "active_shards": 8862,
    "relocating_shards": 12,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 20
}

I have so far tried to rolling restart the data nodes after disabling shard allocation, but cannot see any progress. Could someone be able to provide me a few hints on what to check further?

Comment: [This might Help](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cluster_health.html)

Comment: your cluster has 10 nodes, where 7 of them are data nodes?

Answer (score 4):

You have `"unassigned_shards": 20` in health check response. This is most likely caused because data nodes in the Elasticsearch cluster lack free storage space. As explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html#aes-handling-errors-red-cluster-status-lack-of-free-space) you can:

> - Use the `/_cat/indices` Elasticsearch API to determine which of the
>     indices are unassigned to nodes in your cluster
> - You can also use the `_cat/allocation?v` API to check shard allocation
>     and disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

As this [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-cluster-state-red-cannot-allocate-because-allocation-is-not-permitted-to-any-of-the-nodes-that-hold-an-in-sync-shard-copy/98219/2) states, you may try to run this at your elasticsearch master so it tries to realocate the shred:

`curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed`

In my case, it was able to recover the data and get the following message:

`Elasticsearch cluster is green. Shards: 108 active, 0 initializing, 0 relocating, 0 unassigned...`